# Can I use Kendo.MVC UI controls in my webforms project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, kendo-ui

We purchased all Kendo framework but I have a small project based in webforms and I like to use only a couple of Kendo UI controls, listview and grid.

Can I get the source and compile them or use them in any way?

Comment: I have used the chart in web forms a couple of months back. I needed data from the DB which I stored in a label and used javascript/jQuery to read them.

Comment: How did you include it in the project?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot use the Kendo UI MVC wrappers in a webforms project. You can however use the JavaScript only versions. Simply include the required JavaScript and CSS files to your page. Check the [getting started help topic](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/downloading-kendo).

Comment: I suggest you check the ASP.NET tutorials from our documentation: http://docs.kendoui.com/tutorials/ASP.NET/asp-net-hello-jquery

Comment: Can you answer please What do you mean with `wrappers`?

Comment: The MVC versions of the Kendo UI widgets are called "wrappers".